# Android non-blocking file i/o?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, io, nonblocking

I'm currently writing an async i/o library for Java that has a very similar API to Node.js. I could do the socket part with nio, but there seems to be no FileChannel that extends SelectableChannel so I can't do the file i/o with nio, too.

In Java 7 they added AnsynchronousFileChannel, which allows non-blocking file i/o. Unfortunately, Android does not support it. Is there an equivalent class on Android to do non-blocking file io?

You can find the library here: https://github.com/VanCoding/Node.java

A sample App is located here: https://github.com/VanCoding/Node.java/blob/master/src/node/examples/App.java

Answer (score 2):

> Is there an equivalent class on Android to do non-blocking file io?

Other than your wrapping traditional I/O in a background thread, no, sorry.

Comment: That's sad :( I hope Android will get such a thing in the near future!