# Non Blocking Serial IO call in Java

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Non blocking IO for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4293448/non-blocking-io-for-android)
>   [Android: Unbuffered IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693758/android-unbuffered-io)

Can anyone tell me how to write a NON blocking serial IO read/write in Java?

What needs to happen is a kernel ioctl call to put the device file in non-blocking mode. Question is how to cause java to do that.

Comment: "NON blocking serial IO read/write in Java" - means?

Comment: try this tutorial http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/nio-vs-io.html

Comment: @user370305 that is entirely standard terminology, except for android not usually (specifically) supporting serial ports.  Customized installs might.  Or converters could be used with the USB host API, but the latter would be a very different interface.

Comment: @ChrisStratton _ I figured out. I had doubt on **NON blocking** terms, I thought he refers to UI of Activity. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: This is an entirely normal, technically sound request.  There is no reason to close the question or delete Ivor's answer.  Doing so makes it look like the people exercising moderation powers don't understand the subject matter.

Comment: What needs to happen is a kernel ioctl call to put the device file in non-blocking mode.   Question is how to cause java to do that.  Answer is likely in Ivor's link.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I've edited the information you provided into the question, and reopened it.  I'm *not* going to undelete Ivor's answer; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231

Comment: Hmm... Are you talking about actual serial devices as @Chris suspects? Or are you talking about normal serial file IO? This question could use some clarification...

Comment: @Shog9 there isn't much of a difference.  On unix-style systems, devices are treated as files.

Comment: @RobertHarvey keeping Ivor's answer deleted hides the solution from low-rep users.  Even if the link became invalid, the text of the URL itself indicates the answer.

Comment: Then edit the answer so that it's a real answer, and flag for undeletion.  But the link is already in the comments, above.

Comment: @Chris: there's potentially a big difference if he needs to make ioctl calls vs. using the NIO framework that Ivor links to...

Comment: @Shog9 Do you think nio will work with one and not the other?  There's almost always a choice of doing something by hand, vs having a library do it for you.  Would be interesting to strace an nio solution - I would not be surprised to find ioctl's used.  Unless it merely fakes non-blocking I/O with threads.

Comment: @Chris: that would make an interesting question on its own... Anyway, if the "serial" aspect of this question is unimportant, then it's a duplicate of quite a few others on non-blocking IO in Android. I'll throw a few links in. FWIW: ran across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11048450/android-non-blocking-file-i-o) where the answer suggests that NIO is not useful for file IO.

Comment: @Shog9 - the answers to those questions don't actually provide non-blocking I/O, other than a link or two to the same nio library buried amidst the non-solutions.

Comment: @Chris: yeah - one of these questions could really use an answer that's more than a link...